# How to uniformly distribute JMeter threads throughtout the entire run of the test

Tags: jmeter

I have the following

[image]

but when I run this with 60 threads I don't see the threads being fired off every second. Instead it seems like the requests in the transaction controller are fired off at a rate of 60 requests per min.

Is there a way I can have JMeter create threads at the rate of 60 per minute without a limit on requests?

Comment: You need to use rampup duration in that case

Comment: Can you be slightly more specific I am a little new to this

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Rampup duration in that case. Again that is one time activity, once threads are created they will execute the request and will die / repeat if you need.

[Ultimate Threadgroup plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) is also helpful here.

Generally everybody is interested how much throughput(req per unit time) can server take. So in your case its doing correct job i.e. sending requests 60 per sec.

In practice creating multiple threads per sec is bad practice and IMO such testing is not useful (Why it is required?) because client threads in JMeter is not important but requests sent to server by threads (can be 1-10 or 100) many times and how server responds is important.

If your use case is different then share it in detail and we'll discuss. Hope this helps.

Comment: 'Generally everybody is interested how much throughput(req per unit time) can server take. So in your case its doing correct job i.e. sending requests 60 per sec.' But it seems to be limiting every thread to 60 req/sec so if I have 3 threads that inflates to 120 (anecdotally). Is there a way to limit this to all requests and in a uniform manner (I know it is basically another question so feel free not to answer) 'In practice creating multiple threads per sec is bad practice and IMO such testing is not useful' We are simulating load and our load is greater than one user per second.

Comment: not sure why 3 threads is reaching to 120 req/sec. To achieve uniform throughput uniform throughput plugin is good (https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/). Can you share script if possible ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want JMeter to kick off one thread per second you need to specify **Ramp-Up Period** equal to the number of threads (virtual users) under [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group), if you want 60 virtual users - go for 60 seconds ramp-up.

Also make sure you allow your Thread Group to loop **forever** as if you don't - you will run into a situation when some threads have already done their job and some haven't been started yet.

Example configuration:

[image: JMeter Thread Group Ramp-Up]

Example output:

[image: JMeter Ramp-Up in Action]

More information: [JMeter Ramp-Up - The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-the-ultimate-guide)